# Hi, I am working on this basic python code but I am getting TypeError Issue in it. Can you tell me the issue.?

Tags: python

```
class StudentData:
    def _init_(self, name1, marks, marks1):
        self.name1 = name
        self.marks = user_data
        self.marks1 = user_data1

    def marks_cal(self):
        result = int(self.marks + self.marks1)
        return result
        print("Enter the name")
        name = str(input())
        print("Enter your marks for Maths: ")
        marks = int(input())
        print("Enter your marks for Chemistry: ")
        marks1 = int(input())
        data = StudentData(name, marks, marks1)
        print("Your marks are: " %(data.marks_cal()))
```

---

Hi, Can you please tell me what is the issue in my code. This is the basic python. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: all the `StudentData` constructor parameter names don't match what they are being assigned to

Comment: What are `user_data`  and `user_data1`. Shouldn't those be `marks` and `marks1`?

Comment: also `_init_` needs to be `__init__` if it is meant to be the constructor

Comment: Yeah yeah,those are marks and marks1. 
By mistake, pasted the previous one.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I don't think any of the lines starting with `print("Enter the name")` are supposed to be inside the class.

Comment: your print should probably be `print("Your marks are: %d" %(data.marks_cal()))`

Comment: Yeah, made it constructor and used this print. Working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could be completely wrong but I'll do my best to help.
First lets look at the init statement

Your code:

```
class StudentData:
def _init_(self, name1, marks, marks1):
    self.name1 = name
    self.marks = user_data
    self.marks1 = user_data1
```

I think you just need to reverse some of the code like this

```
class StudentData:
def __inti__(self, name, user_data, user_data1):
    self.name1 = name
    self.marks = user_data
    self.marks1 = user_data1
def marks_cal(self):
    result = int(self.marks + self.marks1)
    return result
```

That should make it so your user defined data is assigned correctly and you can run your test code. (you also had that indented so it looks like the rest of the method declaration)

```
print("Enter the name")
name = str(input())
print("Enter your marks for Maths: ")
marks = int(input())
print("Enter your marks for Chemistry: ")
marks1 = int(input())
data = StudentData(name, marks, marks1)
print("Your marks are: {}".format(data.marks_cal()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class StudentData:

    def __init__(self, name1, marks, marks1):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.marks = marks
        self.marks1 = marks1

    def marks_cal(self):
        result = int(self.marks + self.marks1)
        return str(result)

print("Enter the name")
name = str(input())
print("Enter your marks for Maths: ")
marks = int(input())
print("Enter your marks for Chemistry: ")
marks1 = int(input())
data = StudentData(name, marks, marks1)
print("Your marks are: " , (data.marks_cal()))
```

The above-posted code is working fine.

1- The first problem with your code is the "*init*" statement. The init statement should be "**init**()" (with double pre and post underscores'__').

2- Another Problem is the indentation of your code.